# Cannot call method from another Module : Android studio

Tags: android, android-module

I have two modules in android studio

1. Standard android **app module**
2. **domain module**

The domain module in been added to both `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle`

`include ':mobile', ':domain'` & 
 `compile project(':domain')` respectively like this

Inside domain module I have a class like this :

```
public class DomainUtils {

    Context mContex;
    public DomainUtils(Context context){
        this.mContex = context;
    }
    public  void toast(String string){
        Toast.makeText(mContex, string,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public String returnHi(){
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

But when i try to call     `new DomainUtils(context).toast("hi");`

from a class **inside App module** :

1. The method inside DomainUtils does not execute
2. Program flow does not continue to next line in the calling class ( program flow stops"
3. I do not see any error logs in logcat.

------------**BUT** ----------

When I run the method `returnHi()` It works fine .

Comment: using static is not a solution I think

Comment: If you set a debug breakpoint inside DomainUtils constructor and another one inside toast method. Are they being hit?

Comment: What if try 'Invalidate and Restart' ? And in my app module gradle `compile project(path: ':domain')`

Comment: Does the import of DomainUtils in calling Activity/Class gave any error?

Comment: no it does not give error to import

Comment: @RustFisher did invalidate and restart  and also changed the compile statement like yours but didnt work

Comment: Very strange issue ,Which is the context you are passing `Application` Context or `Activity` Context

Comment: no matter which context  I use , it does not go past that line

Comment: Why downvote  guys I am just trying to find solution to my problem ?

Comment: The problem was not actually related to question asked ... problem and question ..    are not related. Problem existed due to side effect in another piece of code

Comment: vote to close this question  please ... The problem  was not directly related to the question, It was rather due to  side effect of another piece of code

Answer (score 6):

First inside Main Project Folder's `settings.gradle` mention the library

```
include ':app', ':domain'
```

And include versions if available as well , like

```
include ':app', ':library-2.19.0'
```

Now inside `app` folder under path `MainProject>app>build.gradle` include

```
dependencies {
  ..........
  compile project(':domain')
}
```

Again include version details if available. Check out  [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/adding-modules-to-a-project.html)  for more details

Based on the comments, you can do one more verification if library is properly included or not. Clean and rebuild should configure properly, but still just make sure the following is updated by Android Studio .

Check in `app.iml` if the module has got included or not

```
MainProject > app > app.iml
```

There should be an entry in `<component>` tag  like below

```
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="domain" exported="" />
```

---

Edit :

Try to run your `Toast` message inside `runOnUiThread`. It should solve the error.

Comment: I think I have already done what you are suggesting but no luck

Comment: Is the location where you edited build.gradle the wright one? There are more than one . You might be aware but , just in case you missed out..

Comment: yeah  first is settings.gradle, second one is  build.gradle inside app directory  I do not have versionings so The second snippt is not useful for me

Comment: Check out my edit , if it gives any clue. Or else I dont see any exceptions. :(

Comment: Yeah I can see that app.iml things  you have mentioned

Comment: Hope your debugger reaches till Toast message line. If then try with  Toast message inside runOnUiThread ... Its just a wild guess . May be an absolute mistake also... :)

Comment: As I told in previous comment Just try with runOnUiThread inside your DomainUtils

Comment: You are amazing I was mistakely calling that method from BG thread .  Now it works fine as expected.. Please  edit your answer to point that I might be running in background ...  that has to be the accepted answer

Comment: or lets delete this question coz the problem , solution and the title are irreverent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145185/discussion-between-erluxman-and-stallion).

Comment: vote to close this question  please ... The problem  was not directly related to the question, It was rather due to  side effect of another piece of code

Answer (score 3):

Before you build the project don't forget to add the module inside your build.gradle.

```
dependencies {

  compile project(':domain')
}
```

Then while calling the method pass the current class context like as below.

```
 new DomainUtils(YourClassName.this).toast("hi");
```

Comment: I am doing the same

Comment: is there any exception catched.

Comment: can you pass getApplicationContext()

Comment: vote to close this question  please ... The problem  was not directly related to the question, It was rather due to  side effect of another piece of code

Comment: Yes I think, May be some memory issues.

Comment: I never knew I can vote comments too :D thanks for the tip :D

Answer (score -1):

From file settings.gradle add full path module.

include ':your_module'

project(':your_module').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'absolute_path').

absolute_path start from folder container settings.gradle

Comment: I can easily access the class and even auto complete is working , the problem is in runtime

Comment: vote to close this question  please ... The problem  was not directly related to the question, It was rather due to  side effect of another piece of code